# tempusdominus clear minDate/maxDate

Tags: tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am using [tempusdominos jquery plugin](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/) and i am trying to use the [minDate and maxDate feature](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/#minmaxdate) to link 2 time pickers. I can set these values, but it seems impossible to clear these values.
I tried :

```
 $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
    minDate: false
  });
```

and

```
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
        minDate: null
      });
```

[sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYpyed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it like this:

```
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker('minDate', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue. Setting `false` like this worked for me:
`$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker('minDate', false);`